# How to persist One-to-One Hibernate with shared primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have following one-to-one relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Book book;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
}
```

Now I have a function that returns a product already having a book and want to persist it with an entityManager in a transaction. So I call `product.getBook().setProduct(product)` and want to persist both with `entityManager.save(product)`.

But it says `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException id of book is violating Not-Null-Constraint`

The method beeing called for saving the entities is annotated with @Transactional if that helps.

Why does hibernate not generate the ids?

Comment: I doubt very much, that it is correct, that the product and book are to cross-reference each other. This seems fundamentally wrong. In a relational database, usually only one entity references the other's id. You should maybe rethink the structure of your data.

Comment: I took this from here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Comment: There is no instance of the word 'book' on that page. You probably modified a working example to fit your purpose, but accidentally misinterpreted or abstracted the purpose. Which example did you start with?

Comment: I subsituted user with product and address with book so from the context there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every bidirectional association *must have one owning side only (the child side), the other one being referred to as the inverse (or the `mappedBy`) side*. You should remove `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation from the `Product.book`:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    // ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Book book;
}
```

as this annotation uses only on the owning (not `mappedBy`) side.

And whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times. So, you should do something like this:

```java
Product product = new Product();
Book book = new Book();
// ...
product.setBook(book);
book.setProduct(product);
entityManager.save(product);
```

Comment: So PrimaryKeyJoinColumn should be used on Book.product instead? Does this mean, that PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and JoinColumn(name="product_id") is the same in this context? Anyway I still get the same error message.

Comment: You use `@MapsId` already here. You can use either `@MapsId` or `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) of the documentation.

Comment: Now that works if I set the ids manually, but I want them generated and still have the problem, that the id for book is null when I want to save the product entity. Is there no other way then to query for the id of the product that I just saved and use it to save the book?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use? Could you try to use `entityManager.persist(product)` instead of `entityManager.save(product)`

Comment: Do your `Product` entity have another fields marked by `@Id` annotation ? (hibernate specific way for setting composite id)

Comment: I'm using hibernate 5.4.32 (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)

Comment: Only product.id has the id annotation. The product itself has been saved before, just without the book.